# How to run a spreadsheet bound script as the creator (not viewer/editor)

Tags: google-apps-script

I made some script with my spreadsheet, which uses some Trigger and SendEmail functionalities. I have menu items in spreadsheet to control these triggers and sendemails.

Now when I share this spreadsheet with someone other, when he tried to access the trigger or sendemail functions from menu, the script asks for authorization as that user. IF authorized it will function as that user. e.g. send email as that user or make a new trigger as that user. This makes things double and useless

I want that any user accessing the script can use those functionalities, but won't require authorization to run as that user. The script should run as the creator of the sheet, so that no double triggering occurs. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web-app. Web-apps have the ability to run either as the user himself, or as the developer/publisher.

> Under Execute the app as, select whose authorization the app should
>   run with: your account (the developer's) or the account of the user
>   who visits the app (see permissions).
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

This web-app wouldn't have a sheet linked to it, but if you only use 1 sheet you can have the web-app access the sheet through the ID of the sheet. You could use your existing menu-items to trigger the webapp

Would this be a possible solution for your problem?